# C++ windows.h - window doesnt open

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<tchar.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("ClassName");

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG messages;
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszMenuName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wincl))
        return 0;
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, szClassName, _T("ClassName"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 544, 375, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, hThisInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    while(GetMessage(&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
    return messages.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The window doesnt show up/open. I've tried for 6 hours straight to find the problem, it doesn't give me an error in the console, it just creates the `.exe` window but not the other window. I'm new to this, so idk what to do or how to reply to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is wrong:

`wincl.lpszMenuName = szClassName;`

It needs to be this instead:

`wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;`

You are not checking if `CreateWindowEx()` fails (returns NULL):

```
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(...);
if (hWnd == NULL) ... // <-- ADD THIS
```

In this situation, it does fail, because you are not registering the class name correctly, so creating the window will report an `ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS`  (1407) error from `GetLastError()`.

Comment: Don't forget to set `wincl.lpszMenuName` to `NULL`.

Comment: @MartinRosenau it is best practice to zero out Win32 structures before using them, populating only the fields you actually need.

Comment: I always did so, but the OP seems to be missing the `memset` or `ZeroMemory` call...

Comment: No need to `memset`, just declare it as `WNDCLASSEX wincl {};` and it'll automatically zero-initialize.

Comment: Thank you so much Alan Birtles, Martin Rosenau, Remy Lebeau and rustyx!!, I really appreciate it, I am new to stack overflow and it surprised me how fast people respond. Again, ty (: